# How to include boiler plate compass library code

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Currently I am using

```
@import "compass";
```

to include some boiler plate compass code but it doesn't actually do anything.
here's my base.scss files code

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/css3";
#hello{
    width: 200px;
    height: 510px;
    color: blue;
}
```

when it compiles my result is

```
/* line 3, sass/base.scss */
#hello {
  width: 200px;
  height: 510px;
  color: blue;
}
```

I assumed that this would include some more CSS. Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a library I am supposed to download and add to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Compass is designed to be a do-it-yourself toolkit of things that are useful for any project, rather than a prepackaged product like Twitter's Bootstrap.  It does not emit any styles unless you explicitly say so (eg. invoking a mixin).

There are Compass modules out there that are a little more drag and drop like you were probably expecting, but you'll have to hunt them out for yourself.

Comment: thanks for the help. I discovered that the @import is used int he same way as namespaces in other languages. You still have to implement the "method, properties" of a namespace.